# Performing a Regex Expression on a String of which may contain Regex Metacharacters?

Tags: regex, vb.net, string

A function of my application consists of checking a folder path by partial name (The folder names are formatted as such: "ID Name", where 'ID' can be any number of digits and 'Name' could contain any valid folder naming characters.

I only know of the 'Name' part of these folders, not their 'ID'.
I retrieve these folder by their 'Name' (without 'ID') using this:

```
Dim regDirs = New Func(Of String, Boolean)(Function(i) Regex.IsMatch(i, "[\d]+[\s]" & strName, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Where 'strName' is the variable containing the name without the ID. This matches any number of digits (as the ID) plus a space character, plus the Name.
Then I pass this line into:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirRoot).Where(regDirs)
```

And everything work wonderfully, but only for names of which do not contain Regex Metacharacters.

This is where I'm stuck. I tried storing the name in a variable of which can be checked by another Regex Expression before the above one which would escape all the Metacharacters ([\^$.|?*+(){}) so the above expression won't consider them as special characters but I'm not entirely sure how to do this correctly or whether there's an easier way to do it.

I know I could do each character individually using normal String Replace like:

```
Dim tempName as String = strName
tempName = tempName.Replace("[", "\[")
```

But then I'd have multiple lines doing that same thing, doesn't look very elegant and I'm not sure if it's very efficient either.

Help appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET provides the [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) method for exactly this purpose:

```
Dim regDirs = New Func(Of String, Boolean)(Function(i) Regex.IsMatch(i, "[\d]+[\s]" & Regex.Escape(strName), RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
```

Comment: Spent 3 hours rattling my brain around this, can't believe I missed something so simple. Thank you very much~!

Comment: @Primula glad I could help. Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check mark next to it. This will show future visitors that and how your problem has been solved. It will also give me some credit (and a little to you as well).

Comment: Will do.

Though one last thing, how do I then unescape it so that it can be found as a directory? With use of `Regex.Escape`, it's comparing the directories to the escaped versions. I'm not too sure where I would put `Regex.Unescape` with:

`Dim paths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirRoot).Where(regDirs)`

And then there's a loop `For Each path In paths`

Comment: @Primula the result `regDirs` will not contain the escape characters.

Comment: Ah yep, nevermind! It was because the string I was just testing with contained a '.' which didn't exist in the actual folder name.
Thanks again for your help!